# If IL2CPP on unity is compiled, how come people can mod games?

Tags: unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I've been developing a game in unity(called Humanity Clicker, if anyone is interested) so I been doing a lot of research on how the engine works and etc.

It just so happens that there are projects, such as MelonLoader, which are capable of modding basically any Unity game, no matter if using mono or IL2CPP. And while I can understand how they mod mono projects(as its not compiled into machine code), IL2CPP converts MSIL into machine code, and thus should make it basically impossible to mod, since the game's code would be unreadable for humans.

How do tools like that work?

Comment: Not sure how melon actually does it. but you can still inject IL2CPP builds (IL2CPP does not mean 100% immutable). FWIW simple way to mod a game, be it IL2CPP or Mono, is to allow user put their modpack in the streamingassets folder load resources from that folder. [official doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html)

Comment: Would you read the games's code before modding it?

Comment: It's still able to inspect the "code" so that mods can attach to it regardless of whether its Mono or  c++ DLLs.  Check out the doco.